# Java regEx for any letter from any language

Tags: java, regex

Here is the pattern i'm trying to use to accept any letter from any language maximum length of 150 characters in my java program. Output is giving false.I'm expecting true result for the given inputs. Please advise me on the java regex pattern.

```
String pattern = "[\\p{L}]{0,150}";

String input = "any letter from any language like n or ñ  a or à or @ ®";

input.matches(pattern); // false
```

Comment: You have space and `@` characters which aren't there in your character set.

Comment: To add to the comment from @PushpeshKumarRajwanshi, you'd need to change your regex to something like this: `"[\\p{L}@ ]{0,150}"` if you want to allow `@` and spaces

Comment: `[\s\S]` matches any character, `[\S]` matches any non whitespace character.

Comment: @Lino use a character class to check for spaces: `\s`

Comment: @KarelG really depends on which kinds of whitespaces you want to allow. Accepting only a space and rejecting e.g. newlines `\n` is perfectly valid IMO